# Asp.net DropDownList to show items?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, ado.net

```
int CountryID = Convert.ToInt32(ddlcountry.SelectedValue);
```

Here is a `ddlcountry` selected value of what type, 
I mean what is the data type of `(ddlcountry.SelectedValue);` ?

Comment: I'm quite sure you'd be able to figure that out with a *very* short debugging session.

Answer (score 0):

you have to convert it into `.ToString();`

```
string value = ddlcountry.SelectedValue.ToString();
```